# How to pass the value of an @value annotation to the controller in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, boot

I have a spring in which I use the dependencies of: spring-boot-starter-web v-2.7.3, spring-boot-devtools and spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf my purpose is to send an "Invoice" class with the dependencies of a client class and an ItemFactura class to the controller, with the @value annotation I add an environment variable located in the application.properties:

```
factura.descripcion: Deporte
```

I add it with @value to my java invoice class:

```
@Component
public class Factura {

@Value("${factura.descripcion}")
private String descripcion;

@Autowired
private Cliente cliente; 

private List<ItemFactura> items; 

/**
 * @return String return the description
 */
public String getDescription() {
    return descripcion;
}

/**
 * @param descripcion the description to set
 */
public void setDescription(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

/**
 * @return Cliente return the cliente
 */
public Cliente getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

/**
 * @param cliente the cliente to set
 */
public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
}

/**
 * @return List<ItemFactura> return the items
 */
public List<ItemFactura> getItems() {
    return items;
}

/**
 * @param items the items to set
 */
public void setItems(List<ItemFactura> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
```

}

Después de esto inyecto la clase Factura en el controlador:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Factura")
public class FacturaController {

@Autowired
private Factura factura; 

@GetMapping("/ver")
public String verFactura(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("factura", factura);
    model.addAttribute("Titulo_factura", "Esto es el título de una factura");

    return "index";
    
}
```

}

Y por último la llamó en mi index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Facturas</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Aquí se ven las facturas</h1>

<h1 th:text="${Titulo_factura}"></h1>
<h1 th:text="${factura.descripcion}"></h1>



</body>
</html>
```

When I lift again and enter my route I get the error: **Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "invoice.description" (template: "ver-invoice" - line 13, col 9)** and **Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'description' cannot be found on object of type 'com.nodependencyinjection.demo.Domain.Factura' - maybe not public or not valid? **

Mi primera reacción fue cambiar private descripcion por public, pero lo que intento es realizar un encapsulamiento del objeto, la única opción que veo para este error es que mi clase **com.nodependencyinjection.demo.Domain.Factura** y mi **com.nodependencyinjection.demo.Controllers** están en paquetes diferentes, o que para utilizar las variables de entorno haya que agregar una configuración especial en application.properties, la cual desconozco, cualquier ayuda se agradece de antemano

pddt: when I add "factura" only in the html the page loads correctly and I get the hash of the class.

this confuses me...
[image: html image]

Comment: @Configuration in class level, will help to pull values from property file.

Comment: Add the annotation in my Factura class, and it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property is `descripcion` so you need a getter `getDescripcion()` and not `getDescription()`

Comment: I can't believe it was because of the method name... Why does it throw an error if I never make a specific use of it, instead I call the entire "Factura" class, does the variable name influence how they should be called getters and setters? Doesn't it have a merely semantic value?

Comment: "${factura.descripcion}" translates to factura instance getDescripcion()... but using "${factura.description}" in you page could work, because you have a getDescription().

Answer (score 0):

The value of an @value annotation is pass through application.properties file to the controller and value is Static.